# How do I "find: inactive jump gate" At the beginning of Kingdom's End in X4: Foundations?

Tags: x4-foundations

How do I do this?

[image: find: inactive jump gate]

Its somewhere in the Great Reef system, if I leave the mission changes to travel to Great Reef. There's nothing on the map

[image: map of Great Reef]

The mission description provides no hints.

[image: Blazing the Trail mission]

Nor does the briefing

[image: Blazing the Trail mission briefing]

Turning on the autopilot in Great Reef immediately disengages it.

---

**Edit:** it's slightly to the NNE from Boron Warf. Even looking right at it, trying to target it, adds nothing to the map.

[image: I can see it but my sensors can't]

When you go through the gate you have exactly the same problem, but now in the next system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt+F4, Uninstall.

Even after finding [how to use the long range scanner](https://youtu.be/KQYz6y54wDU?si=thFHhLYu4QkXH1-q&t=248) -- it's not in any of the tutorials, you have to comb through the "help" which is just links to youtube videos to find out that it's the secondary fire button.

The scanner can't locate this, whatever it is, even when it's right in front of your ship:

[image]

---

**Edit:** The scanner can find the gate, but only at the range where you can already see it yourself
[image]